# Idiomatic way serialization in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Currently I am working on a elisp major mode that makes uses of hashtables across sessions. So every time the major mode is initialized, the tables are loaded into memory. During and at the end of the session they are written to a file. My current implementation writes the data in the following way:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (prin1 hash-table (current-buffer))
  (write-file ("path/to/file.el"))))
```

Loading the data at the beginning of the session is done via read and is something like this:

```
(setq name-of-table (car
        (read-from-string
         (with-temp-buffer
           (insert-file-contents path-of-file)
           (buffer-substring-no-properties
        (point-min)
        (point-max))))))))
```

It works but I have the feeling that this is not the most beautiful way to do it. My aim is: I want this major mode to turn into a nice clean package that stores it's own data in the folder where the other data of the package is stored.

Comment: Put the initializer into the Lisp code you are evaluating anyway? Saves you from doing any elaborate stuff when reading -- then you can just `eval-buffer` and the code you add when writing just needs to be `(setq variable` and the closing paren at the end.

Comment: looks simple and doable. ^^ I will see how that works and if it goes smoothly I will tag your post as answer. :)

Comment: No need to convert to a string, simply do `(read (current-buffer))` in the temporary buffer.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I implement

Write to file:

```
(defun my-write (file data)
  (with-temp-file file
    (prin1 data (current-buffer))))
```

Read from file:

```
(defun my-read (file symbol)
  (when (boundp symbol)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents file)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (set symbol (read (current-buffer))))))
```

Call to write:

```
(my-write "~/test.txt" emacs-version)
```

Call to read

```
(my-read "~/test.txt" 'my-emacs-version)
```

Comment: You can use `(goto-char (point-min))` followed by `(read (current-buffer))`, that way you don't have to create a string.

Comment: @Lindydancer Edited with your suggestion.

Comment: Great! However, I would suggest placing the `goto-char` right after the `insert-file-content`, that way it will be easier to read. In addition, is there any reason why you simply not return the read value instead of setting a variable? That code would be very straight forward: `(defun my-read-from-file (file) (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-content file) (goto-char (point-min)) (read (current-buffer))))`

Comment: @Lindydancer There is problem `with-temp-file` is implemented by `with-current-buffer` which is implemented by `save-current-buffer` which expects a `char-or-string-p` as argument. I have problem serialize a `cl-struct` with `hashtable` if not converted to string.

Comment: Huh? `(read (current-buffer))` and `(read (buffer-string))` should be equivalent (if point is at the beginning of the buffer), with the exception that in the latter case, a potentially large string needs to be created. `with-temp-file`, which you mentioned, is used by the writer function, which is a different problem. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: I recognized the problem,  with `insert`, I need a string arg.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following solution, inspired by the first answer here:

```
(with-temp-buffer
   (insert "(setq hash-table ")
   (prin1 hash-table (current-buffer)
   (insert ")")
   (write-file (locate-library "my-data-lib"))
```

And during the init of the major mode, I just do:

```
(load "my-data-lib")
```

No need for and read-operation and the plus is that I also don't need to give any filepath, just the fact that there is such a file somewhere on the load-path is enough. Emacs will find it. 
elisp rocks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The package `desktop` can do it for you:

```
(require 'desktop)
(unless (memq 'hash-table desktop-globals-to-save)
  (nconc desktop-globals-to-save (list 'hash-table)))`
```